# e String vibrating against fret

Tags: electric-guitar, setup, noise

I bought a second hand Ibanez from a dealer recently with a floating Lo Pro Edge bridge.

When I play the open e string it fuzzes a bit, just like a vibration against the first fret.

can you help me?
I tried everything but nothing seems to work

Comment: When you say first fret - do you mean the one nearest the nut?

Comment: Since it's new, why hasn't it gone back to the supplier?

Comment: If it was purchased new from a dealer, they usually offer a free (or discounted) setup for guitars they've sold. Take it back and ask them to look at the problem. Don't try to fix it yourself at this point.

Comment: You say you've tried everything. What constitutes everything? Anything 'permanent' may have invalidated the guarantee.

Comment: I didn't describe well the situation, the guitar is used sorry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After asking an expert I resolved the problem by adjusting a bit the neck